# Create a new column, based on the value of another column in pandas

Tags: python, numpy

In a dataframe, I have a column for name of different countries and I want to create a new column with their regions like if the country is India, the region should be Asia etc. I already have tried using np.where, but seems like I am doing something wrong. Following is the code that I tried:

```
Region = np.where(country_name == 'US' , "US", 
                 np.where(country_name == ('Brazil' or 'Canada' or 'Peru' or 'Chile') , "Rest of America", 
                 np.where(country_name == ('South Africa 'or 'Egypt' or 'Morocco' or 'Algeria' or 'Ghana'), "Africa", 
                 np.where(country_name == ('Afghanistan'or 'Armenia'or 'Azerbaijan' or 'Bahrain'or'Bangladesh'or 'Bhutan'or 
                                           'Brunei'or 'Burma'or 'Cambodia'or 'China'or 'East Timor' or
                                           'Georgia'or 'Hong Kong'or 'India' or 'Indonesia'or 'Iran' or 'Iraq'or 'Israel'or 'Japan'or
                                           'Jordan'or 'Kazakhstan'or 'Kuwait'or 'Kyrgyzstan'or 'Laos'or 
                                           'Lebanon'or 'Malaysia' or 'Mongolia'or 'Nepal'or 'North Korea'or 'Oman'or 'Pakistan'|
                                           'Papua New Guinea'or 'Philippines'or 'Qatar'or 'Russia'or 'Saudi Arabia'or 'Singapore'| 
                                           'South Korea'or 'Sri Lanka'or 'Syria'or 'Taiwan'or 'Tajikistan'or 'Thailand'or 'Turkey'or 'Turkmenistan'or
                                           'United Arab Emirates'or 'Uzbekistan'or 'Vietnam'or 'Yemen'), "Asia", 
                 np.where(country_name == ('Spain'or 'Italy' or 'Germany'or 'United Kingdom' or'France'), "Europe", "Unchange")))))

Below is the data:

     Entity        Region   Code       Date   Total confirmed deaths (deaths)   Total confirmed cases (cases)
0   Afghanistan     Asia    AFG     2019-12-31  0   0
1   Afghanistan     Asia    AFG     2020-01-01  0   0
2   Afghanistan     Asia    AFG     2020-01-02  0   0
3   Afghanistan     Asia    AFG     2020-01-03  0   0
4   Afghanistan     Asia    AFG     2020-01-04  0   0
5   Afghanistan     Asia    AFG     2020-01-05  0   0
6   Afghanistan     Asia    AFG     2020-01-06  0   0
7   Afghanistan     Asia    AFG     2020-01-07  0   0
8   Afghanistan     Asia    AFG     2020-01-08  0   0
9   Afghanistan     Asia    AFG     2020-01-09  0   0
10  Afghanistan     Asia    AFG     2020-01-10  0   0
11  Afghanistan     Asia    AFG     2020-01-11  0   0
```

But this code is working only for the first country like only for Brazil, South Africa, Afganistan and Spain.

Comment: You should be using `isin` (pandas). All these -> `'Brazil' or 'Canada' or 'Peru' or 'Chile'` are being evaluated before `country_name == ('Brazil' or 'Ca....`. This is not doing as you think

Comment: You should just consistently replace `country_name = ('a' or 'b' or ...)` with `coutry_name in ['a', 'b', ...]`

Comment: @yatu I am really sure how isin can work here, as it will only write true and false value. Do you mind elaborating your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

```
list_1 = ["Iceland", "Norway", "Sweden", "Finland","Denmark","United Kingdom", "Ireland",
              "France", "Belgium","Netherlands", "Luxembourg","Monaco", "Portugal", "Spain",
              "Andorra", "Italy","Malta","San Marino", "Vatican City", "Germany", 
              "Switzerland", "Liechtenstein"," Austria", "Poland", "Czech Republic", "Slovakia",
              "Hungary","Slovenia","Croatia", "Bosnia" ,"Herzegovina", "Serbia", "Montenegro", 
              "Albania", "Macedonia", "Romania", "Bulgaria","Greece", "Estonia", "Latvia", 
              "Lithuania", "Belarus", "Ukraine", "Moldova"]
    list_2 = ['Brazil' , 'Canada' , 'Peru' , 'Chile', 'South America']
    list_3 = ['Afghanistan', 'Armenia', 'Azerbaijan', 'Bahrain' ,'Bangladesh',  'Bhutan', 
              'Brunei', 'Burma', 'Cambodia', 'China', 'East Timor','Georgia',  'Hong Kong', 
              'India' , 'Indonesia', 'Iran' , 'Iraq' ,'Israel' , 'Japan','Jordan', 'Kazakhstan',
              'Kuwait' , 'Kyrgyzstan' , 'Laos', 'Lebanon', 'Malaysia' , 'Mongolia', 'Nepal', 
              'North Korea', 'Oman', 'Pakistan','Papua New Guinea', 'Philippines', 'Qatar', 
               'Saudi Arabia','Singapore', 'South Korea', 'Sri Lanka', 'Syria', 'Taiwan'
               'Tajikistan', 'Thailand', 'Turkey', 'Turkmenistan','United Arab Emirates', 
              'Uzbekistan', 'Vietnam', 'Yemen']
    list_4 = ['United States']
    list_5 = ['South Africa','Egypt' , 'Morocco' , 'Algeria' , 'Ghana', 'Africa', "Egypt"]



     conditions = [
            (df['Entity'].isin(list_4)),
            (df['Entity'].isin(list_2)),
            (df['Entity'].isin(list_5)),
            (df['Entity'].isin(list_3)),
            (df['Entity'].isin(list_1))
                     ]
        choices = ['US',"Rest of America","Africa","Asia","Europe"]
        Region = np.select(conditions, choices, default='Rest of the world')
```